# Sappling Addon:- Leaves and Tree branches separated in Particle System

Tags: sapling-addon

**Aim**: - I want to create a forest with Sapling add-on and particle 
system.

**Problem:-**
          Leaves are separated from branches

**Achievement**: -

**Without Particle System**: - I am able to render all the trees with leaves in object mode + rendering.

**With Particle System**: - I had created some different trees with sapling add-on.

**Steps followed:-**

1. I had created the different trees with sapling addon.
2. Created Group for trees with leaves selected.
3. Add Particle system

   3.1 selected Hair option, used tree Group as particle
4. I am able to distribute the different trees with random size.
5. **But some trees leaves are separated from branches..**

I had tried the different options, but didn't succeed.

1. Tried to combine the leaves and branch/base.. but..it's not good option..

Kindly help me to solve the above problem or suggest to follow the different steps..

Comment: Why isn't joining the leaves and branches a good solution for you? You can still use different materials, they will have separate UVs... And the grouping it all together should also avoid this issue.

Comment: I have the exact same problem: although the trunk and the leaves are in one group, the leaves appear some distance off the trunk. This may be a bug with the particle system and the sapling tree addon. A great pity. As suggested by TLousky, joining the trunk and the leaves into one mesh (not one group) is the solution.